# plugin function undefined in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

The documentary nuxt.js shows that it works. [Link](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context)
But when I call my plugin function on my components life cycle hook "mounted" it says "TypeError: Cannot read property '$ProgramApi' of undefined".
But on a regular method it the plugin works fine in the same component. So the settings must be right

I'm pretty new to nuxt.

```
<script>
export default {
  data()  {
    return {
      programs: []
    }
  },
  mounted: () => {
    console.log(this.$ProgramApi.agenda());
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      this.$ProgramApi.conferenceRooms().then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `mounted` function to be Regular function. don't use ES-6 syntax.

instead of:

```
mounted: () => {
  console.log(this.$ProgramApi.agenda()); // this will refer to mounted instance
},
```

use:

```
mounted() {
  console.log(this.$ProgramApi.agenda()); // this will refer to vue instance
},
```